# Way to see Github's network view of a project in git locally?

Tags: git, github, graph, visualization

I find it somewhat ridiculous that I have to push branches to Github to be able to get a view what I can work with. Is there a way to get a user friendly view locally in git?

The `git log --branches --remotes --tags --graph --oneline --decorate` doesn't really do it for me.

I really like the github/network graph view.

Comment: It turns out I may also try GitUp which looks extremely promising. http://gitup.co/

Answer (score 3):

The tool I have found the best for this is GitUp ( http://gitup.co/ ) which shows you a highly customizable visualization with most of the things you would want to know about your project's state.

It is also really fast, so you can just keep it open while you work and it will always be up to date.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows or OS X, you can use [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) which has such a feature:

> [image]
>
> On the left side you have the repositories and when you select one, you see the nice graph there. Screenshot from their website.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of breaking out the GitHub client for that thinking it would be focussed mostly on their website.

Comment: @alper It could be useful sometimes. I always used the command line. :) Don't forget to mark the answer if you consider so.

Comment: Graph is not available with the latest release for Windows?

Comment: Feature not available on macOS as of today

Answer (score 1):

For linux users: the "network view" is featured in [gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk), [QGit](https://github.com/tibirna/qgit), and probably many other git GUIs.

A comprehensive list of graphical interfaces (for all client OSes) can be found [here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools#Graphical_Interfaces), and git-scm has a very nice list with screenshots [here](https://git-scm.com/download/gui).