# Git branch horizontal viewer

Tags: git, logging, viewer

I'm looking for some tool to show me commits and branches in horizontal view like Github, until now I found [Gitgraph.js](http://gitgraphjs.com/) but do you know an alternative?

I don't really want to do commits or something else in there.

[image: Gitgraphs.js]

[image: GitHub]

Answer (score 2):

I used gMaster for a long time and I loved it! The branch explorer was a godsent for me: It is horizontal, every commit is a bubble with several indicators and it has a lot of info.

I recently I realized I wasn't getting any updates and after searching, the domain gmaster.io is removed and there seems to be no trace of it.

Looks like it is now called plasticscm.com, which I am installing right now to test.

Edit: Its a full VCS now, it needs its own server :( just asked about the UI: https://forum.plasticscm.com/topic/23633-what-happened-to-gmaster-is-there-a-ui-to-work-with-local-git-repos/

Edit 2: In the meantime, ungit (https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit)  seems to be relatively similar, although still vertical:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkBVAi3oKvo

Edit 3: Found a couple more questions about this, but honestly almost all suggestions are clones :(

[Way to see Github's network view of a project in git locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949102/way-to-see-githubs-network-view-of-a-project-in-git-locally)

[Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs)

Comment: Actually, gMaster looks exactly what I was looking at :( anyway, thanks for sharing I'll try ungit.

Answer (score 1):

It's not horizontal, but vertical is just as good when talking about a tree.

I use the command line [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).

Lately my favorite is using `git log --pretty=oneline --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate=short`

I typically alias it in my `.bashrc`. I like to call it `glog`

With this solution, you don't have to use any external software (like github or your .js) and the graph is all ascii characters (which I like). Also it works great in ssh sessions with a remote server.

A quick google got me to this helpful article: https://mackyle.github.io/git-log-compact/

Comment: Yes, I know about pretty git log but I was curious if anyone knows some horizontal tool viewer. Anyway thx for answer dude.

Comment: I think perhaps it's hard to find horizontal ones since doing it horizontally restricts the space available for text (for branches, tags, commit messages, dates, etc...). I understand the desire for a horizontal one, since the horizontal axis is easily understood as increasing time.